# How to set a radiobutton checked property based on a condition

Tags: html

I want two radio buttons IsCool and NotSoCool:

I want them linked together so they can't be checked at the same time.

I thought this code would be a simple starting point for getting it to work:

```
<input type="radio" value="True" checked="true ? checked : null">
<input type="radio" value="False" checked="true ? null : checked">
```

So I was thinking the first radio button would be checked and the second wouldn't.

They're both checked.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them both the same name attribute:

```
<input type="radio" value="True" name="cb" />
<input type="radio" value="False" name="cb" />
```

Radio buttons must share the same name attribute in order to function properly. This allows you to only have one active at any time.

Simple **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M5cGh/)**.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of radio buttons, you just need to give them the same name